# Elemento siguiente y anterior de un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hola estoy intentando iterar sobre un dataframe para obtener el siguiente o el anterior en función de lo que necesite, me lo he planteado de la siguiente manera pero lógicamente no funciona.

```
for name, group in df[df["air"] == False].groupby("id"):
    tiempo = group["MarcaTemp"].max()
    #Extraer el id del indice que nos crea pandas en el dataframe eje: 56
    #Esto lo hago porque quiero obtener el indice del maximo valor de la marca de tiempo 
    #que he obtenido en el paso anterior
    idCol = df.loc[df['index'] & df[timestamp]==tiempo]
    #Lo que quiero es obtener el siguiente valor de ese indice osea
    idCol = idCol+1
    # y que me devuelva el indice 57 con el fin de extraer la marcaTemporal 
    # de este no se me ocurre otro modo de sacar el anterior al maximo o al minimo.
```

Nota: En el código cuando hablo de index, me refiero al indice que crea pandas en el dataframe, no se exactamente si se puede llamar directamente así, como si fuera una columna.

Comment: Hola Peter, ¿quieres el siguiente elemento dentro del grupo o el siguiente elemento en el DataFrame en general (puede pertenecer o no al mismo grupo)?

Comment: Te comento, en tiempo almaceno el maximo valor con la condicion de que air es False, pero luego quiero el siguiente del total del dataframe osea tanto True/False, que simplemente seria el siguiente al punto obtenido en time!